# Drools kie java client object modified in rule not getting in result

Tags: java, drools, kie-server

I am using kie-server 7.0 and kie-java-client 7.0.
I have written a simple rule in work bench:-

```
rule "Hello World"
when
    a:CartDetails(minPurchaseAmt==10000)
then
    a.setMinPurchaseAmt(20.0f);
    System.out.println( "Test rule executed success");
end
```

This is my client code:-

```
Command<?> insert = commandsFactory.newInsert(fact,     "CartDetails",true,"DEFAULT");
Command<?> fireAllRules = commandsFactory.newFireAllRules();
Command<?> factObjects = commandsFactory.newGetObjects();
Command<?> batchCommand = commandsFactory.newBatchExecution(Arrays.asList(insert,fireAllRules,factObjects));
ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> executeResponse = rulesClient.executeCommandsWithResults("couponengine_1.0", batchCommand);
```

Im getting "SUCCESS" in response but not the updated object. (As I am calling setMinPurchaseAmt() in 'then' part of rule)

Please tell if you need more inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use update function to instruct drools engine to update value of fact. Add update(a) in then part of the rule. Try with this approach and share results

Comment: Found the fix for it. The issue is not in rule part. It's in model. The model (date object) which I have defined on rule server and the one which I am sending from client doesn't match. Which is why rule is not getting fired.